# Nested touch events

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-seekbar

I have a horizontal `RecyclerView`. The items in that `RecyclerView` contain a vertical `SeekBar`. The `RecyclerView`and the `SeekBar`scroll/slid fine, but it is inconvenient to move the `SeekBar` because a slight horizontal move results a scroll of the `RecyclerView`.

I want to disable the `RecyclerView` scroll when the user touches the `SeekBar`, or to reduce the sensibility of the `RecyclerView`to a horizontal movement.

Comment: If you have tried any code, edit your question with it.

Comment: You can use this in your xml file, Where you have defined `RecylerView`  
 `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`. It will disable scrolling of `RecyclerView`.

Comment: You can disable it dynamically `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` and if you want to enable/disable then you can make boolean variable and do it according to your requirements.

Comment: Welcome, buddy. :)

Comment: @RakeshKumar I am disableing the scroll on `onInterceptTouchEvent`, because I need to know where the user touches, so `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` by it self doesn't help much. But combining it with my previous code:                                                         `if (disableScroll) {
                    rv.stopScroll();
                }
                rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(!disableScroll);`                                     works pretty well, but not perfect. I'd like to hear more suggestions.